# Concatenate many 1xn arrays using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have one 1xn array like this:

```
data = [-2 -1 -3 -5 2 5 8 9 ..... 8]
```

Now, I want concatenate this with other similar 1xn arrays:

```
data2 = [0 3 0 0 ..... 5]
```

`final` is a big matrix with many rows

```
[data]
[data2]
...
[data1000]
```

What is the Python code for this?

Comment: you have the operative word.... np.concatenate((a, b...))

Comment: `data` as displayed looks like a (n,) 1d shaped array (no commas, so it's not a list).  You want to make a (m,n) array, with `m`m rows?

Comment: exactly finally is a matrix mxn,  @NaN np.concatenate() no work,

Comment: Try `np.array` on a list of the 1d arrays: `np.array([data, data2, data3, ... ,data1000])`

Comment: How is np.concatenate failing? Is it returning an error, or an undesired result?

Answer (score 2):

```
totalData = [data, data2, data3, ... , data1000]
```

Would be the easiest way to do this if you have no way to iterate over the data.

Comment: but i need mxn matrix

Comment: The list of lists will act like a a matrix when you want to retrieve or change data points. In the example above `totalData[2][2]`will be equal to the third data entry of `data3`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [1,2,3,4]
data2 = [1,2,3]

#put the list of lists to a DataFrame which will make the equal length and fill missing elements with NA. Then use values to get the M*N numpy array.
pd.DataFrame([data,data2]).values
Out[371]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  1.,   2.,   3.,  nan]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `np.vstack`

```
import numpy as np
data = [-2, -1, -3, -5, 2, 5, 8, 9, 8]
np.vstack([data, data])
# [[-2 -1 -3 -5  2  5  8  9  8]
#  [-2 -1 -3 -5  2  5  8  9  8]]
```